# TCP server started but connection refused inside a container

Tags: docker, go, tcp, tcplistener, docker-network

I have a `golang` application which starts a `TCP` server on port 8080. Every thing works fine when I run the app native.

However when I run it as a container, I am unable to even `telnet` to the port from within the container itself.

```
docker ps 

9bb08785b728   dp_local   "/bin/dragonpit-linux"   8 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   8080-8081/tcp   youthful_villani
```

```
docker exec -it youthful_villani sh

/ # telnet localhost 8080
telnet: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

Note: used `0.0.0.0` as well as `127.0.0.1` in place of localhost

TCP Server starting code

```
        var err error
        var lc net.ListenConfig
        th.listener, err = lc.Listen(ctx, "tcp", "0.0.0.0:8080")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        clog.Info(ctx, "tcp protocol listening", "listenAddr", th.addr)
```

I hard-coded the address to see whats the issue.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.18.0 as builder
RUN mkdir -p /build/
ADD .   /build
WORKDIR /build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o tcp_server


FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 8080 8081
RUN mkdir -p /server/config
ADD config  /server/config/
ENV SMC_PATH /
COPY --from=builder /build/tcp_server /bin/
RUN apk update
RUN apk add busybox-extras 
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tcp_server"]
```

Output of `docker-inspect`

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "a70f476a8a7376b1e5a935b67170145f2222e059c5b2a1a63da50519a491babf",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": null,
                "8081/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/a70f476a8a73",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "7b6b9d0d5f83b8136919ac0f765167f6d380a8d836f460a0243bedeb3489a013",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "16563fdda1d5059bb6e2800455f2e87ac8d02e040386eae595a215692e849d76",
                    "EndpointID": "7b6b9d0d5f83b8136919ac0f765167f6d380a8d836f460a0243bedeb3489a013",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Docker running command and starting logs

```
docker run dp_local  
                       
25T14:59:46.367075600Z","caller":"build/main.go:24","msg":"Starting listening","listenAddr":"0.0.0.0:8080"
```

Edit:
I just printed out the `Addr().String()` of `TCP Listener`, I got this

```
{"level":"info","ts":"2022-04-25T15:44:28.952095700Z","caller":"server/tcp.go:65","msg":"[::]:8080"}
```

Comment: How are you starting the container?  Do you in fact get the `tcp protocol listening` log message?  Also note that Go 1.18.1 fixes a couple of important crypto-related things and you might update the compiler, but that shouldn't affect your plain-text TCP listener.

Comment: @DavidMaze, updated, yes I get the message. Add to that when I run as the app directly, there is no issue.

Comment: Offtop: If you want to expose your application on port 8081 outside of docker (map port from 8080 inside docker to 8081 outside) do it with a flag while running container `docker run -p "8081:8080" my_image_name`.
Also adding configs on image build time is not a good habit - you're rebuilding container each time just to change the config. I would suggest to build it similarly to https://fabianlee.org/2020/01/26/golang-using-multi-stage-builds-to-create-clean-docker-images/ and load config from envs (eg. https://github.com/caarlos0/env).

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the newest image you build?
Sometimes even when you rebuild your image and your trying to run the new one, docker can use the previous/cached image version by reusing previously running container - happened to me few times in the past.

To kill all the running and stopped containers you can use:
`docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -aq))`

Comment: If you want it to be easy to fix by others then please provide a minimum working example of go code with the issue - not parts of the code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question here. It was actually a TCP parameter which was set incorrectly and caused issues. The culprit was MTU. For reference: [https://www.baeldung.com/cs/tcp-max-packet-size#:~:text=The%20maximum%20size%20of%20a,size%20should%20never%20exceed%20MTU](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/tcp-max-packet-size#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20size%20of%20a,size%20should%20never%20exceed%20MTU).

Comment: It would be helpful if you expanded your answer with an example. I am running into a similar problem as your initial question, but it does not seem like an MTU issue. The loopback interface on my host and in my container has the same MTU of 64 Kb.

Answer (score -2):

Two Assumptions based on your question

1. You want to expose ports 8080 and 8081

> `EXPOSE 8080 8081`
> 2. You are running the docker image and the client on same machine

In that case you need to bind the Docker container ports to ports on an interface on the local machine. Let's use localhost. You docker run command should look like

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080/tcp -p 127.0.0.1:8081:8081/tcp dp_local
```

This will bind container ports 8080 to 8080 and 8081 to 8081 on localhost of local machine.
Read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)

Comment: Thanks for your input but you completely misunderstood the trouble. Issue is not binding container ports to host ports, but unable to access a tcp server running from inside the container itself.